# AWS - Creating a Quick Production-Quality Service

Tags: architecture, cloud, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-opsworks

I need to create a simple yet Complete AWS Production-Quality DataStore as a service. So for example, lets say I need to store an employee database and offer an API to manage/access this DB.

I figure a standard cloud architecture would include stuff like:
user management, database, application server, API gateway, monitoring and recovery, auto scaling, auto data backups and configuration for multiple zones.

I would expect for there to be a way for me to pretty much just define my data schema and a little configuration and have everything else just work. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [AWS CodeStar](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/welcome.html)? This provides templates for several server frameworks and languages so you can focus on your code, not on quite so much of the infrastructure.

It depends on how little work you want to do. The requirements on your Ops team increases left to right: CodeStar, ElasticBeanstalk, AWS ECS, AWS OpsWorks, raw EC2 instances.

The question is if you want a easy onramp for infrastructure, or if you're really looking for a "No Code" solution like Quickbase, Filemaker Pro or Microsoft Access.

Comment: Looking for easy onramp but "complete" as in everything is already there as in multi-zone and backups.

Comment: Follow up: I did use Codestar and found it be very minimalistic. The templates themselves come with disclaimers such as "not suitable for production". In short, I'm still looking for a full reference implementation of a simple database that would be considered "complete" and "production ready".

Comment: Beware: If you do go with Codestar, it seems that it creates your Code repo on a VM and if you make the mistake of deleting that VM, you will lose all your work permanently. I recommend putting your source code repo elsewhere. Only 61 questions on Stack Overflow for CodeStar may also be an indicator that there is not much traction for it.